# Do Relativistic Gasses of Identical Particles Obey the Ideal Gas Law?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, ideal-gas

I am trying to determine the equation of state and see if $PV = nRT$ is satisfied. For an ultra-relativistic gas of identical particles in a volume $V$ the energy (I am assume there is no potential) is $E = c\sum_{i = 1}^Np_i$ where $p_i = \sqrt{p_{xi}^2 + p_{yi}^2 + p_{zi}^2}$. Hence I estimate the number of microstates with energy $E$ is

$\Omega(E) = \bigg(\frac{1}{\Delta p}\bigg)^{3N} \int_{0}^{E/c}\Pi\bigg(4\pi p_i^2 dp_i\bigg) = \bigg(\frac{E}{c\Delta p} \bigg)^{3N} \frac{(8\pi)^{N}}{(3N)!}$

I used the fact that $\int_{0}^{E/c}\Pi p_i^2dp_i = \frac{2^N}{(3N)!}\bigg(\frac{E}{c} \bigg)^{3N}$

Now using the equation $\frac{1}{T} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial E}$ I obtain $E = 3Nk_BT$. However I am not sure how to find an equation for pressure and volume. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: There should be an $V^N$ in you expression of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have to use
$$dE=TdS-PdV+\mu dN$$
$$\frac{P}{T}= \left. \frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right|_{N,E}$$
Where $$S=k_B\ln\Omega$$

---

Comment: Slightly confused about how (dS/dE at const N,V) = P/V? Should have been 1/T...

Comment: Ah! Sorry, it should be $\partial S/\partial V$.  I should confirm it from the book. It's now corrected.

Comment: The first equality implies that entropy $S$ can be measured in the same units as pressure $P$. How is that possible? In addition, it is impossible to differentiate $S$ with respect to $V$, provided $V = const$.

Comment: It's should be $E$, I have corrected it!

Comment: But you still have $[P] = [S]$.

Comment: Could be P/T = (dS/dV, at const T), since then TdS-pdV=dU=0, for constant T.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation is easier in the canonical ensemble. Use
$$P=-{\partial F\over\partial V}$$
where the free energy is given by
$$F=-k_BT\ln{\cal Z}$$
Note that for free particles, the partition function factorizes
$${\cal Z}=z^N$$

Comment: Is the no. of particles varying, for it to be in cannonical ensemble? If so, it should  become a Grand-Cannonical ensemble.